# Maven filter src/main/resources of a JAR dependency

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, filtering, maven-resources-plugin

My maven top level project refers to a common-db project. In this project I have a spring file which defines the DB parameters.

However, I want the top-level project to define the DB parameters through the profile and inject these into the spring config file in /src/main/resources.

The top-level project only does the filtering on its own /src/main/resources files and ignores those located in the JAR dependencies.

How can I do this?

Comment: put your top-level spring config file into the same classpath location, so it overrides corresponding common-db project file

Comment: I dont want to have any config file in the top level project. This is already defined in the common-db project. I have several projects referencing the db project and want this config in one place instead of several.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to depend on common-db but then modify its contents to change the parameters in the config file? Ok, if you really want to do that, you could do something convoluted where you use [`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) to expand the common-db jar, then overwrite / filter its contents, and then use a custom `jar:jar` execution to re-jar up the dependency and ship it with your application.

But, wow - why would you jump through all these hoops? Like @hoaz suggested, just place your application-specific config in the same classpath location so that it is loaded before common-db's default configuration.  This is the convention followed by many, many Java libraries.